# How to create commands/utilities in a visual studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution in VS 2013 that have a few utility tasks that need to be done once in a while, for example rebuild some files that are embedded in the output executable.

Right now I am using a test to run these, just because it is simple to run some code from the IDE, but I don't like it – it's not a test.

My question is how would you create some utilities or commands that can be run from the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make your utilities runnable from a commandline (for example, if they're in batch scripts or standalone helper executables), then you can use the **External Tools** functionality of Visual Studio.

Here's the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx) for that topic.

I don't have VS 2013 handy, but I've done this with previous versions of Visual Studio.  It is a little more natural than running a test to invoke some helper utility tasks, although that works in a pinch.

You could also cobble together a pre/post-build event that runs the utility task.  It's unclear what you are doing periodically, but if it's a pretty lightweight operation, it might not hurt to do it there.

Comment: Hmmm. I think a pre-build is exactly what I need. Thank you

Comment: @bbrik would you mind marking this as the answer if you found this to be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to create and run commands using .NET and Visual Studio automation model in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a look at it!